# Where's the difference between $\vDash$ and $\Rightarrow$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm sorry if that question has already been asked. 

Sometimes in propositional logic when proving "$\phi \rightarrow \psi$ is a tautology" using truth tables people write $\psi \Rightarrow \phi$. 
But isn't that the same as proving $\psi \vDash \phi$ since truth tables are a semantic proof method? 
Where's the difference between $\vDash$ and $\Rightarrow$?

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If the answers there don't fully answer your question, then feel free to ask another question.